# Redux-thunk dispatch is not a function

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I have the following action

```
export function getAllBooks() {
  return function(dispatch) {
     return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/books')
    .then(response => dispatch(retrieveBooks(response.data)));
  };
}
```

The issue is when i call this action, I get in the console

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function
>       at eval (eval at ...

that is the `dispatch` in the `.then(response => dispatch(retrieveBooks(response.data)));` is playing up

I've tried removing all other middle-ware except redux-thunk  to no avail

The only place the action is used is in

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { fetchBooks : () => dispatch(getAllBooks) };
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call the `getAllBooks` action creator and pass the inner function to `dispatch`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return { fetchBooks: () => dispatch(getAllBooks()) } //note the dispatch call
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close :(